# Fastest way to convert string like id=1&type=2 into array in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I need to change it into :

```
$arr['id']=1;

$arr['type']=2;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get parameters from this URL string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-this-url-string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use: [parse_str()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
void parse_str(string $str [, array &$arr])
```

> Parses str as if it were the query string passed via a URL and sets variables in the current scope.

Example:

```
<?php
    $str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
    parse_str($str);
    echo $first;  // value
    echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
    echo $arr[1]; // baz

    parse_str($str, $output);
    echo $output['first'];  // value
    echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
    echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz

?>
```

Comment: This answer should have a warning for the first method, since it will overwrite variables in global scope.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to parse what looks like a query string, just use [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$input = 'id=1&type=2';
$out = array();
parse_str($input, $out);
print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [type] => 2
)
```

You can optionally not pass in the second parameter and `parse_str()` will instead inject the variables into the current scope. *Don't do this in the global scope*. And I might argue don't do it at all. It's for the same reason that `register_globals()` is bad.

Comment: parse_str does not return a value, so that code wouldn't work right.

Comment: Who can remember which PHP functions mutate an array, return an array, have the array as the first parameter or the second and so on? :)

Answer (score 2):

See [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str).

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array();
$values = explode("&",$string);
foreach ($values as $value)
{
  array_push($arr,explode("=",$value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) with the second argument**, like this:

```
$str = 'id=1&type=2';

parse_str($str, $arr);
```

`$arr` will then contain:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [type] => 2
)
```