# How can I get parameters from a URL string?

Tags: php, url-parsing

I have an HTML form field `$_POST["url"]`, having some URL strings as the value.

Example values are:

```
https://example.com/test/1234?email=xyz@test.com
https://example.com/test/1234?basic=2&email=xyz2@test.com
https://example.com/test/1234?email=xyz3@test.com
https://example.com/test/1234?email=xyz4@test.com&testin=123
https://example.com/test/the-page-here/1234?someurl=key&email=xyz5@test.com
```

etc.

How can I get only the `email` parameter from these URLs/values?

Please note that I am not getting these strings from the browser address bar.

Comment: I'm a little confused, please elaborate the Q...

Comment: Are you saying/asking for the URLs to be treated as strings?

Comment: If you want to "match" the email part from strings, like in your examples, use regular expressions. Could be as simple as `/(email=\w\@\w\.\w)/` or more advanced matching techniques. Just giving you the idea. See `preg_match` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I extract query parameters from an URL string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784243/how-do-i-extract-query-parameters-from-an-url-string-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get URL query string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8469767/608639)

Answer (score 532, accepted):

You can use the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) for that.

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['email'];
```

If you want to get the `$url` dynamically with PHP, take a look at this question:

[Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Comment: its working but i am getting error in logs like this :
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: query

Comment: Also, you will have a question mark if it is the last character in the query.
I used this: `if (strpos($urlParts['path'], '?')) {
    $urlParts['path'] = substr($urlParts['path'], 0, strpos($urlParts['path'], '?'));
}` to remove it from the end.

Answer (score 155):

All the parameters after `?` can be accessed using `$_GET` array. So,

```
echo $_GET['email'];
```

will extract the emails from urls.

Comment: This isn't the answer to the question, but this is the answer I was looking for when I asked the Googles for the question, so +1 for answering Google correctly.

Comment: This may not be the answer to question but is the correct and easiest way to get URL parameters--if they are set correctly:

`https://example.com?email=myemail@example.com`


`$email = $_GET['email'];
$email === 'myemail@example.com';`

Comment: can somebody explain why this is not the best answer. it works exactly query params works.

Comment: @SaurabhSingh the question is asking how to extract parameters from a URL string that is passed to the server as part of a request. this awnser only get parameters of the page rtequest, it is not how to get parameters from a URL string.

Comment: @SaurabhSingh It is because the question is, if the url parameters are unknown, how would you get them. If the URL parameters are known, then this is be correct answer.

Answer (score 57):

Use the [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) methods. `parse_url()` will parse a URL string into an associative array of its parts. Since you only want a single part of the URL, you can use a shortcut to return a string value with just the part you want. Next, `parse_str()` will create variables for each of the parameters in the query string. I don't like polluting the current context, so providing a second parameter puts all the variables into an associative array.

```
$url = "https://mysite.com/test/1234?email=xyz4@test.com&testin=123";
$query_str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query_str, $query_params);
print_r($query_params);

//Output: Array ( [email] => xyz4@test.com [testin] => 123 )
```

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned in another answer, the best solution is using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

You need to use a combination of `parse_url()` and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

The `parse_url()` parses the URL and return its components that you can get the query string using the `query` key. Then you should use `parse_str()` that parses the query string and returns
values into a variable.

```
$url = "https://example.com/test/1234?basic=2&email=xyz2@test.com";
parse_str(parse_url($url)['query'], $params);
echo $params['email']; // xyz2@test.com
```

---

Also you can do this work using **regex**: [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

You can use `preg_match()` to get a specific value of the query string from a URL.

```
preg_match("/&?email=([^&]+)/", $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // xyz2@test.com
```

#### [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Also you can use `preg_replace()` to do this work in **one line!**

```php
$email = preg_replace("/^https?:\/\/.*\?.*email=([^&]+).*$/", "$1", $url);
// xyz2@test.com
```

Comment: I'm using Laravel. The `preg_replace()` method works best here because it doesn't throw error when `query` isn't defined in the URL unlike `parse_url()`, and it's a one liner!

Answer (score 7):

Use `$_GET['email']` for parameters in URL.
Use `$_POST['email']` for posted data to script.
Or use `_$REQUEST` for both.
Also, as mentioned, you can use `parse_url()` function that returns all parts of URL. Use a part called 'query' - there you can find your email parameter. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: OP said he is not getting URLs from `address bar`. These URLs are just strings `IN` the code.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the below code to get the email address after `?` in the URL:

```js
<?php
if (isset($_GET['email'])) {
    echo $_GET['email'];
}
```

Comment: The OP requested extracting variables from a string not the URL in current page. parse_url() is the correct answer assuming the string is correctly formatted.

Answer (score 3):

I a created function [from Ruel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11480852/1307387).

You can use this:

```
function get_valueFromStringUrl($url , $parameter_name)
{
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if(isset($parts['query']))
    {
        parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
        if(isset($query[$parameter_name]))
        {
            return $query[$parameter_name];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
$url = "https://example.com/test/the-page-here/1234?someurl=key&email=xyz5@test.com";
echo get_valueFromStringUrl($url , "email");
```

Thanks to @Ruel.

Answer (score 1):

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$uriArray = explode('/', $uri);
$page_url = $uriArray[1];
$page_url2 = $uriArray[2];
echo $page_url; <- See the value
```

This is working great for me using PHP.

Comment: Can you please try to elaborate the answer more. It's hard to get what you mean by the above answer.

Comment: This isn't getting the "email" query parameter. And the URL isn't the request URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
$web_url = 'http://www.writephponline.com?name=shubham&email=singh@gmail.com';
$query = parse_url($web_url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $queryArray);

echo "Name: " . $queryArray['name'];  // Result: shubham
echo "EMail: " . $queryArray['email']; // Result:singh@gmail.com
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57010223/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

A much more secure answer that I'm surprised is not mentioned here yet:

[`filter_input`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

So in the case of the question you can use this to get an email value from the URL get parameters:

`$email = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );`

For other types of variables, you would want to [choose a different/appropriate filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) such as `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`.

I suppose this answer does more than exactly what the question asks for - getting the raw data from the URL parameter. But this is a one-line shortcut that is the same result as this:

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
$email = filter_var( $email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );
```

Might as well get into the habit of grabbing variables this way.

Comment: whooops, didn't see the last line of the questions about not getting this from the URL... still leaving this here in case it's helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

In [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel), I'm using:

```
private function getValueFromString(string $string, string $key)
{
    parse_str(parse_url($string, PHP_URL_QUERY), $result);

    return isset($result[$key]) ? $result[$key] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic function which parses string URL and gets the value of the query parameter passed in the URL:

```
function getParamFromUrl($url, $paramName){
  parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $op); // Fetch query parameters from a string and convert to an associative array
  return array_key_exists($paramName, $op) ? $op[$paramName] : "Not Found"; // Check if the key exists in this array
}
```

Call the function to get a result:

```
echo getParamFromUrl('https://google.co.in?name=james&surname=bond', 'surname'); // "bond" will be output here
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird that in over 11 years, nobody has posted an actually good function to do this here. So let me do it. I am not sure if the `! is_string` check is actually needed, but it does not hurt.

```php
/**
 * Retrieves the value of a specified query parameter from the given URL.
 *
 * @param string $url The URL from which to retrieve the query parameter.
 * @param string $arg_name The name of the query parameter to retrieve.
 * @return ?string The value of the specified query parameter, or null if it doesn't exist.
 */
function get_url_arg( string $url, string $arg_name ): ?string {

    $query_string = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY );

    if ( empty( $query_string ) || ! is_string( $query_string ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    parse_str( $query_string, $query_args );

    return $query_args[ $arg_name ] ?? null;
}
```