# Prefill webpage from Lotus Notes client application

Tags: html, wordpress, lotus-notes

Looking to prefill a webpage (a form in a wordpress site) from a lotus notes application.  My investigations to date show that using the query strings behind the urlname should work - however I am missing something here.

```
www.url.com/register?fname="bob"&sname="smith" etc...
```

I thought this could be done, but am not sure where the starting point would be?

Ideal solution - webservice from the owner of url.com to allow us to populate and get a response once done.  They are not keen to do this as it does not save them any time, just our business.

I am looking to understand how to prepopulate the webpage so that the user just has to submit the form at url.com.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question actually is. If it's about populating an HTML form with values in a query string, this is covered many times on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-this-url-string) and on the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var). However, it sounds like you don't own/have control of the domain and the WordPress installation, so I don't know what you're really asking.

Comment: Yes, I do not have control over the wordpress site - so all I am looking to do it open the registration website with the firstname / surname etc already completed, so all the user has to do is hit the register button.  I thought it was straight forward just using the query string, however using the url https://login.mailchimp.com/signup?, and adding a email into the querystring https://login.mailchimp.com/signup?email="bob@url.com" it does not prepopulate.  I suspect I am missing the most obvious starting point?

Comment: The person in control of the website needs to have setup the query string functionality in advance, so if they have not already or are not willing to do that it will not work in the way you envision.

Comment: I'm just speculating here, but you may be running into a deliberate restriction that is intended to prevent spammers from auto-populating and submitting the registration form. I suggest that you try your code against a web site that *is* under your control, and if you can make it work but it still fails for the site you're really trying to use it on, then you'll at least know that you're dealing with a site-specific issue.

Comment: I had the same thought @RichardSchwartz - was aware that I sounded dodgy.

Comment: Thanks for the response @wanasten - I did not know that it was something that had to be enabled on their side.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could go mega-sneaky and use the [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) to launch a browser session on your client. It has full control over the browser and can sniff out the fields you need to populate. I wrote some [simple code](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-9GCJQ9) for starters - but the samples on the original web site might be more comprehensive.