# Php get url string value

Tags: php, url

Hi all i am new in `php` and i have some question how to do that.

I have URL like this

```
http://localhost/royale/?lang=am
```

And I need to take "am"

I search and find this

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

but it return "lang=am"

Comment: You want to get the value of lang? Can you write your question in a bit more detail in the actual post?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-this-url-string

PHP function parse_url

Comment: you should definitely read some php tutorials

Answer (score 4):

you can get the value as..

```
<?php
      $lang = $_GET['lang'];
      echo $lang;
?>
```

or if you are not sure about the value of parameter, then check it first by..

```
 <?php
      if(isset($_GET['lang'])){  
         $lang = $_GET['lang'];
          echo $lang;
      }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is the value of "lang", `$lang = $_GET['lang'];` // this is 'am'

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
// Check first if lang is on the URL query string
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    // If so, then do what you want with $_GET['lang']
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    echo  $lang;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The parse_url with the parse_str function will take a URL string and create an associative array from the arguments

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['lang'];
```

Answer taken from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11480852/3944304 (I tried linking to it before, but was told my answer was trivial)

Comment: How is `email` part related to the question again?

Comment: Good, now I can +1 you :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm amazed that nobody has mentioned the article in the PHP docs about $_GET. This is what you are looking for, OP.

[$_GET @ PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)