# decoding php not working

Tags: php, mysql, json

i want to post a json object to php.

```
var user = {username:"test", password:"test", name:"test",  
email:"test@hotmail.com"};
var str_json = JSON.stringify(user);
$.ajax({
        url: '/register_API.php',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
           console.log('success');
        },
        data: user
    });
}
```

In php i want to insert it into mysql:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($data,true);

$username = $json['username'];
$password = $json["password"];
$email = $json['email'];

$insertSql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email)
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email');";
```

The $data string contains: username=test&password=test&name=test&email=test%40hotmail.com, but i can't get the variable by decoding...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your not sending the stringified json data: str_json  your trying to send the user object.  change data: user  to data: str_json

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get parameters from this URL string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-this-url-string)

Comment: Specify `data: str_json,` above your success function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `data: user` to `data: str_json` and then

change `$data = file_get_contents('php://input');`

to `$data = $_POST['data']`

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending a JSON string, you're sending a Javascript object which jQuery is translating to a set of parameters in the outgoing POST request. Your data will be available to PHP in $_POST - no need to decode it first.

Look for it like this:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to send raw JSON as text and have that be in the post body and not treated as an encoded form.

In this case I think your PHP code is right. Send the stringified JSON as you are, but set the data type  to dataType: "text".

I think you will be able to read it with

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
//works like explode, but splits your data where finds "=" and "&" too.
$output = preg_split( "/ (=|&) /", $data);
```

This will return an array of your data. where:

```
$output[0]="Username";
$output[1]="test";
```

This can be useful if you have fixed data.