# CakePHP HttpSockets send array of paramms

Tags: php, cakephp

I get a problem when make GET request (I can say any request).

`$link = 'http://URI/PATH/?param1=1&sid=2&sid=3&sid=4'
 $http = $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
        $res = $HttpSocket->get($link);`

if check the request

```
pr($http);
```

I see :

```
[line] => GET /URL/PATH/?param1=1&sid%5B0%5D=2&sid%5B1%5D=3&sid%5B2%5D=4 HTTP/1.1
```

And I'm getting empty response because server doesn't know parameters like `sid%5B0%5D=2`

When I try to send parameters as array : `$data = array('param1' => '1', 'sid' => array('2','3', '4'));`

I see the same changes `%5B0%5D` - additional indexes.

How to fix it?

Unfortunately , I can not change server side, but if send GET request in Browser, I'll get normal response in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a get request, you can get the parameters like this:

- $param1 = $_GET['param1'];
- $sid= $_GET['sid'];

Tip: use diferente names for the parameters. You have multiples sid. Use sid1, sid2, sid3...

Update: you can get the parameters like this:

```
$link = 'http://URI/PATH/?param1=1&sid=2&sid=3&sid=4';

$query_str = parse_url($link, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query_str, $query_params);
print_r($query_params);
```

Reference: [How to get parameters from a URL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-this-url-string)

Comment: Impossible, The server is not my property, I can send requests and get response from it. BTW, it works, if not use cake HttpSocket.

Comment: Found a solution for you! Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-this-url-string

Comment: It's not for me. I have not problems to parse requests.The problem is send request array with cake. `$link = 'http://URI/PATH/?param1=1&sid=2&sid=3&sid=4'`