# Retrieve the video ID

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to retrieve a video ID from a link, but the returned result is NULL:

```
$myurl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aSJ2nRUcTk&list=PLIaLMmGmfJ03L5A1Xoyxa_034xxSurqrO";

preg_match('/?v=(.*)&(index|list)/', $myurl, $match);

var_dump($match);
```

I am looking for this video ID: -aSJ2nRUcTk

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11480852/1419321

Comment: https://eval.in/458929 - no need for regex

Comment: Never heard about these functions, let's say it is not a URL and I would to use preg_match

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/sitecom/www/details.php on line 10

Answer (score 4):

You could do it without regex via exploding on the `?` (or doing a substring or other method to get only what's after the `?`) and parsing the query string into an array with `parse_str`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

```
$str = end(explode("?","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aSJ2nRUcTk&list=PLIaLMmGmfJ03L5A1Xoyxa_034xxSurqrO"));
$params = parse_str($str);
echo $params['v'];
// will echo -aSJ2nRUcTk
```

Comment: Thanks dude, if I would like to use preg_match, how can I proceed that?