# PHP return character after value in string

Tags: php, strrchr

I have a dynamic string that looks like this...

```
/tester?bc=7&tester=orange
```

Using PHP I am trying to return the single value after **bc=**

I have looked at **strrchr** but that doesn't seem to let me specify just returning one character, how should I be doing this?

Comment: haven't you used `$_GET` yet? or this string is literally inside a variable? just use `parse_str`

Comment: The string is inside a variable and not being generated by $_GET

Comment: so in this case, you would want to return `7` ? is `bc=7` will always be right after `?` ?

Comment: Yes, I would want to return 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get parameters from a URL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the value is not from the request, you might want to use something like this:

```
$parsed = parse_url('/tester?bc=7&tester=orange');
parse_str($parsed['query'], $query);
```

The `$query` would contain this:

```
array(2) {
  ["bc"]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["tester"]=>
  string(5) "orange"
}
```

Please mind that `max_input_vars` directive affects `parse_str`, so if your string would be extremely large, it might cut some parts.

Best regards, Alexander