# Cant send extra variable to php server

Tags: java, php, android, upload, server

I've successfully uploaded the file to my php server.

However, sending extra information to the server does not work.

My code is as follows:

```
conn.setRequestProperty(Config.KEY_COURSE_TITLE, course_title);// trying to send course_title (a string variable) to php server

$course_title= $_POST['course_title']; // trying to access sent data
```

Full code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15358822/

Comment: Try URL query parameters. Refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-this-url-string

Comment: Thanx a lot bro. It works . Sometimes simple things cant come out from brain. Actually I have a project deadline on tuesday . Thats  why I think I did not figured out what to do . Thanx again :) @SomanDubey

Comment: added same as answer, glad that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Added from comment as answer]

Try URL query parameters. Refer this - 
[How to get parameters from a URL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-this-url-string)