# pass variable value in action url php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How to pass variable values into url. Here is my code

```html
<?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       echo $v=$_POST['n'];
      } ?>
<form method="post" action="/user/<?php echo $v; ?>">
<input type="text" name="n">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

After giving input value and click on submit shows in url:

if input value is raj after click on submit in url i want to display

/user/raj

Comment: There are dozens of tutorials on this out there, and plenty of SO questions. This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string

Comment: what is /user/ its a directory?

Comment: no i write static

Answer (score 2):

1. The requirement can be achieved by using javascript.

   ```
   <form id="myForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return false">
   <input type="text" name="n">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
   ```

   using jquery

   ```
   $("#myForm").on("submit",function(){
    var val=$("input[name='n']").val();
    $(this).attr("action","<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>/user/"+val);
     $(this).submit();
     })
   ```

Comment: when the submit is clicked the form will look fro a user directory so to prevent that change the action to be : `$(this).attr("action","<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>/user/"+val);`

Answer (score 0):

Use method="get" in your form tag.

Comment: in url shows user/?n=raj&submit=Submit i want to display /user/raj.

Comment: @narendra u will need to re write the url with .htaccess

Comment: my file name is 36a07d684f5d8e0a9b572b74bf9cb1c101ac3337.file.header.html
then how to write this code.

Comment: @narendra Based on your code, when you load the page $_POST is empty so your action will be /user/ . after this, when you write 'raj' in input box and post the form, $_POST['n'] contains raj and action will be 'user/raj/'