# How to get any url pattern present in URL string

Tags: php, regex, url

I need to get url value form the given url string, for example I have below url

```
$url = http://www.example.com/news?q=string&f=true&id=1233&sort=true&pf=http%3A%2Fo%2fox.ru
```

from above url if any url is present means I need that value, above is not constant, randomly I get any format of url , But I need only the url from the given URL string.I reffered  here [How to get parameters from a URL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string). In that they use static parameter , but I dont know which parameter have the url value.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just loop over the $_GET variable, you will get all variable keys and values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.example.com/news?q=string&f=true&id=1233&sort=true&pf=http%3A%2Fo%2fox.ru";
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $output);
echo print_r($output, TRUE);
?>
```

You can also use this code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

**solved your issue please check this code it will help you more**

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.example.com/news?q=string&f=true&id=1233&sort=true&pf=http%3A%2Fo%2fox.ru";
$total_part = parse_url($url);
parse_str($total_part['query'], $query);
foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.'=>'.$value."<br>";
}
?>
any further help i am available here
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: its my pleasure @Thiyagu please vote up and mark as answer it will more help to me

Comment: Ya already I upvoted for you , but Only able to accept answer after 5mins