# Codeigniter : How to get ID from URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to ask, how to post ID to database from URL, I can see this ID in the last url.
my Url :

```
http://localhost/rekammedis/index.php/pasien/tambah_rm/3
```

I'm using uri to get $id_pasien value but when I post to database this value is null/empty not posted.

my model :

```
function tambahrm($id)
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $username = trim($this->session->userdata('id'));
    $id_pasien = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = array(
        'tgl_berobat' => $this->input->post('tgl_berobat'),
        'anamnesa' => $this->input->post('anamnesa'),
        'diagnosa' => $this->input->post('diagnosa'),
        'therapi' => $this->input->post('therapi'),
        'keterangan' => $this->input->post('keterangan'),
        'id_user' => $username,
        'id_pasien' => $id_pasien,
    );

    if ($id == 0) {
        return $this->db->insert('tbl_riwayat', $data);
    } else {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        return $this->db->update('tbl_riwayat', $data);
    }
}
```

here is result :
[Id_pasien remains unfilled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdmFf.png)

Comment: Try to put echo to make sure u getting the value from the url... By referring codeigniter url structure, it will assign to the function parameter itself... So check `$id` whether it getting the value or not.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string

Comment: what do you send here function tambahrm($id) <-- ?
because you could just do
$id_pasien = $id; you should be getting 3.

Comment: Half of that code should be in controller. Model shouldn't cooperate with input class but receive variable from controller instead. What are you getting when you put this in model: `exit($this->uri->segment(3));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use URI routing, you can also retrieve information about the re-routed segments:

```
$this->uri->segment(n);
```

Where n is the segment number you wish to retrieve.

In your case it would be:

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

Comment: still **null** in database.

Comment: did you try to print it before inserting to see what value you are getting?

Comment: @Just_Do_It Wrong. First segment is first one after `index.php`. So **3** is final answer.