# URL not passing in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Passing a javascript variable using  tag in iframe by attaching variable like this "+var+" but its not passing value to next page . is there any different way or any bug in my code please suggest.

here is my code.

```
    <script>
    var user = "user@user.com"; 
    </script>

 <iframe src="http://127.0.0.1/ve2/ve2/www/kitchen-sink/api/fm/df.php?user="+user+""></iframe>
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: All your code is doing is defining a variable, include all relevant code

Comment: check it now @PatrickEvans

Comment: @uttamsharma this is not how Javascript works. You have to change the src attribute of the iframe via javascript. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp for more information on how to set attributes.

Comment: That iframe part isn't in javascript `+user` there is meaningless

Comment: so can you please suggest me how can i open a url in a iframe and pass a javascript variable value to next page @BRO_THOM

Comment: Hi Uttam. Welcome to SO. Don't be disheartened by the downvotes on your question - it's just a way for the community to keep the content on this page organised, clean and useful. To help us help you better please read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and rework your question to include the proper context, a [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a clear question.

Comment: so can you please suggest me how can i open a url in a iframe and pass a javascript variable value to next page  @PatrickEvans

Comment: @uttamsharma I've included an answer for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute javascript directly, it has to be executed from script tags OR via an event.

```
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
<script>
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    var user = "user@user.com";
    iframe.setAttribute('src', "http://127.0.0.1/ve2/ve2/www/kitchen-sink/api/fm/df.php?user=" + user );
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you efforts but its still not working

Comment: This example is working. How are you determining it's NOT working?

Comment: df.php file fetching the value from url and echo this value and its not printing anything. that mean its not working.

Comment: <?php 
$user = $_GET['user'];
echo $user;
?> try with this simple code .

Comment: Please look at [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string) to get the query parameters from a URL in PHP

Comment: @uttamsharma please provide us a `var_dump` or `print_r` of your `$_GET` variables (during the call).

Comment: when i simply send a value like this df.php?user="user" its working but when i send data using a variable its not display anything