# Can't populate form input using php and url

Tags: php, html, forms, url, populate

I'm having some issues populating my input html tag with the parameter in the url.

Here's the Url I'm using:
www.website.com/index.html?inventory=100

And here's the basic html going on

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>


<input type="text" name="inventory" value="<?php echo 00((isset($_GET["inventory"]))?htmlspecialchars($_GET["inventory"]):""); ?>"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Help!

Comment: What is it you want to do? `00(functionCall)` is never going to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get parameters from a URL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to populate the input form box with the parameter given in the url on page load. In this case, 100

Comment: Also that "00" before functionCall is a typo. Not sure how that got in there