# How to get values after .php

Tags: php

I am wondering how I can grab all the values from the URL after .php?

Example:
`http://localhost/api/test`

**API = api.php**, just .htaccess.

And I am wondering how I can grab only "test" from the URL, or al the values if more, **/test/test1/test2**

I've tried `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` but it doesn't work for me, error output saying that `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` is undefined. Is there any workaround?

Comment: $_GET if it's set this way ... $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] if not

Comment: you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string)

Comment: But i am not doing api.php?a=test1&b=test2
SO $_GET is useless.
Im trying to get the path after http://localhost/api/

Comment: Then your best chance is to get `$url =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` and then `$url = epxlode(...` then use `$url[4]` etc.. or you could replace the 'http://localhost/api/' with '' first.

Comment: What server are you using? Internally your server likely _rewrites_ `/api/test` to something like `api.php?q=test`

Comment: you need to get url using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] after that store into a variable and seperate using substring like this $str = "http://localhost/api/test"
echo substr($str, strrpos($str, "/") + 1); it will print test

Comment: @MikeRunac if you have `?` in url ... $_GET shouldn't be useless ...

Comment: Looks like *"friendly URLs"* for a RESTful API : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Using parse_url() you can retrieve url components

```
$url = "http://localhost/api/test";
$myurl = parse_url($url);
echo  $myurl['path'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps for you

Step One: write in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^(.+)/?$ test.php?url=$1
```

Step Two: test.php file with following code

```
<?php

   $url = $_GET['url'];
   echo '<pre>';
       print_r($url);
   echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**NOTE:** you can call `explode` function on `$url` variable

**`rewrite module`** must be on in Apache server.

[image]

**Note i think this will solve your problem**

script is self explanatory but if confusion then tell me .

```
<?php
  $url = $_GET['url'];

  echo '<pre>';
      print_r($url);
  echo '</pre>';

  //echo '<pre>';
      ///print_r(explode('/',$url,4));
  //echo '</pre>';

  list($file,$controller,$method,$params) = explode('/',$url,4);


  echo "<hr/>file:" . $file;
  echo "<hr/>controller:" . $controller;
  echo "<hr/>method:" . $method;

  echo "<hr/>params:" ;
  echo '<pre>';
      print_r($params);
  echo '</pre>';

  ?>
```

**Output 2**
[image]

Comment: @mike-runac support back if it really helped then mark as answer and thumb.

Comment: Passing everything through as an URL parameter is a bit *old skool* - you'd normally redirect everything that's not an existing file/directory/(or symlink possibly) to the routing script that checks `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to work out what action to perform.

Comment: but old school tricks always  problem solver. :) BTW you way is also right

Answer (score 0):

You can find all you are looking for in the $_SERVER variable ([php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php))
Just print_r the value of $_SERVER and see what information is there... You will see quite easy what you will need.
You can then use string functions to isolate the part you need in the URL or query string to fetch whatever you need.

Also...

If a .htaccess is used with rewrites, they will probably be sent in the $_GET variables. To be sure, you need to post some of your .htaccess where the rewrites are being done.