# Reusing query string variable

Tags: php

I am trying to reuse a variable passing from one query string to another.

My initial code:

```
$p_arr = getProfileInfo($theMemberID);

$sMemberNickName = $p_arr['NickName'];
$_GET["username"];
echo $sMemberNickName;
$html =<<<HTML
<p><a href="https://firstsite.com/page/membership?username=$sMemberNickName" alt="" target="_blank">SUBMIT</a></p>
```

On clicking SUBMIT query string:

```
https://firstsite.com/page/membership?username=JDoe
```

How to get the user name from the query string above into a new query string:

```
https://secondsite.com?username=JDoe
```

Comment: What does `getProfileInfo()` function do?

Comment: What are you expecting this line to do `$_GET["username"];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get parameters from a URL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string)

Comment: But you already have it in your $_GET request.

Comment: So I assumed that this would give me what Im looking for:  <a href="https://secondsite.com/page/membership?username=$sMemberNickName" alt="" target="_blank">SUBMIT</a>