# How can I get an ID from a SQL filled table?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, html-table

I made a table which is filled with SQL data. When I click on a row, it takes me to a different page (using javascript). On this page I want to show all the data from the clicked row only. How can I get the ID from a table filled with SQL data? Im talking about the ID of the SQL row.

```
echo "<table>"; 
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<th>".'Stof'."</th>";
                                            echo "<th>".'Score'."</th>";
                                            echo "<th>".'Datum'."</th>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                            foreach ($result as $pers) {
                                                echo "<tr data-href='detail.php'>";
                                                echo "<td>".$pers->stofid."</td>
                                                <td>".$pers->melden."</td>
                                                <td>".$pers->datum."</td>";
                                                echo "</tr>";
                                            }
                                            echo "</table>";
```

The data-href is my page reference, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show ID in table add this before last line in your `foreach` statement:

```
echo "<td>".$pers->id."</td>"
```

And don't forget to add `th` element in your table `tr` section (above `foreach`)

```
echo "<th>id</th>";
```

And if you wanna pass that ID to next page (`detail.php`) then change first line in your `foreach` statement into this:

```
echo "<tr data-href='detail.php?persId=".$pers->id."'>";
```

Comment: where would I put this?

Comment: put this on last line in your foreach

Comment: This isn't a complete solution, and will change the way the table looks.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski That last suggestion might actually be better than my answer. I still maintain that adding a column might not be required, but... Good suggestion.

Comment: @meephparganmanpoelermakisto798 this is separate question - ask(or find) it in StackOverflow . At strarting point you can find info about: how to read url parameter in php - here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string

Answer (score 1):

Unless you put the `id` in the table somewhere, it's not possible. I recommend doing the following:

```
echo "<table>"; 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>".'Stof'."</th>";
echo "<th>".'Score'."</th>";
echo "<th>".'Datum'."</th>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach ($result as $pers) {
    echo "<tr data-href='detail.php' data-id='".$pers->id."'>";
    echo "<td>".$pers->stofid."</td>
          <td>".$pers->melden."</td>
          <td>".$pers->datum."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

That way, you can change whatever JavaScript code turns your `data-href` into a link into code that generates `detail.php?id=34526` (using the `data-id` value also. Then `detail.php` can, if it receives an `id` `$_GET` parameter, only show details from that row. (Make sure the user's allowed to read the row with that id, or you'll be introducing a security vulnerability!)

Comment: I can't help more without seeing the bit of JavaScript.