# GET method does not support +, _ signs

Tags: php, get

I got the string as GET value

```
http://example.com?author=example_2
```

So when I try to read **author** get value it gives only **example** part! Tell me please how can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get parameters from a URL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string)

Comment: Can you show us how you read the values?

Comment: There's no special meaning for `_` in URLs (`+` yes, it should become a space) - so in your example `$_GET['author'] = 'example_2'` - so there's something you're not showing us.

Comment: I am typing echo $_GET[author] to print it but it gives the part without _ sign

Comment: Now that was my fault. I typed wrong reg ex in htaccess!