# How to convert string to an associative array in php from post data

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, post

I have string like "name1=firstValue&name2=secondValue&name3=thirdValue" how to convert the string to associative array.

Comment: Take a look at [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: Wouldn't `$_GET` give you this information? I'm guessing those are arguments to your URL?

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for is here: [How to get parameters from a URL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string)