# How to extract data FROM URL between slashes [PHP]

Tags: php, extract

I have

```
{$input = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCA2PjAHmNw&list=RDGMEM_v2KDBP3d4f8uT-ilrs8fQVMXJu6RlDf2O4&index=7'}
```

Wanna to get JCA2PjAHmNw

I've just tried this:

```
{$input = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCA2PjAHmNw&list=RDGMEM_v2KDBP3d4f8uT-ilrs8fQVMXJu6RlDf2O4&index=7'}
{$r = preg_match_all('#/mk_([^/]*)#', $input, $matches)}
{print_r($matches[0])}
```

But nothing happening

Comment: There is no `mk_` in the string right?

Comment: Would like to extract data between = and &

Comment: You can look at this post to get url parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string

Comment: Yes!, works as hell :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
{$url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGseLn0zSI4&list=RDGMEM_v2KDBP3d4f8uT-ilrs8fQVMXJu6RlDf2O4&index=9'}
{$parts = parse_url($url)}
{parse_str($parts['query'], $query)}
{$query['v']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
$data = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCA2PjAHmNw&list=RDGMEM_v2KDBP3d4f8uT-ilrs8fQVMXJu6RlDf2O4&index=7';
preg_match_all('~\?v=(.*)&~isU', $data, $return);
print_r($return[1][0]);
```