# How to split url parameters with ampersand as array

Tags: php, arrays, explode, array-splice

I want to split the parameters sent through URL.
Here is my text.

> "mytext=A & B
> Company&anothertext=20&texttwo=SampleText&array[1]=10&array[2]=20"

Expected output:

> ['mytext'=>'A & B Company', 'anothertext'=> 20, 'texttwo' =>
> 'SampleText',  array[1] => 10, array[2] => 20 ].

I tried with `explode('&', $params)` and `parse_str($url_components['query'], $params)`;

both giving only `A` as result. I need as `'A & B Company'`. How to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get parameters from a URL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-can-i-get-parameters-from-a-url-string)

Comment: The `A & B Company` is the real problem....

Comment: You either need to url encode the values (specifically the `&` in `A & B Company`), or you need to write your own parsing for it. No non-custom PHP function will some how understand which `&` you want it to treat as values and which to treat as delimiters.

Comment: your original text is already wrongly encoded. is it supposed to be url-encoded? because in url-encoding it should have been `mytext=A+%26+B+Company&anothertext=20&texttwo=SampleText&array%5B1%5D=10&array%5B2%5D=20`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)?

See: https://3v4l.org/L2UZa

The result is:

```
array(5) {
  ["mytext"]     => string(2) "A "
  ["B_Company"]  => string(0) ""
  ["anothertext"]=> string(2) "20"
  ["texttwo"]    => string(10) "SampleText"
  ["array"]      => array(2) {
    [1] => string(2) "10"
    [2] => string(2) "20"
  }
}
```

This differs slight from what you want because of the `&`. if you could replace the `&` with the URL encoded version `%26` it would work.

See: https://3v4l.org/OXfsD

The result now is:

```
array(5) {
  ["mytext"]     => string(2) "A & B_Company"
  ["anothertext"]=> string(2) "20"
  ["texttwo"]    => string(10) "SampleText"
  ["array"]      => array(2) {
    [1] => string(2) "10"
    [2] => string(2) "20"
  }
}
```

Basically the `&` is an **anomaly**, it shouldn't have been there in the first place. URL query parameters should be made with [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode), or something equivalent, which would have replace `&` by `%26`.

Comment: I need mytext as `A & B Company` not as `A`.

Comment: @SaravananDS I agree. Would it be possible to replace the `&` with `%26`? That's the URL encoded version.

Comment: idk what format his string is, but url-encoded isn't it. looks like he got a string that is SUPPOSED to be url-encoded, but either has been encoded incorrectly (a bugged encoder) or decoded incorrectly (a bugged decoder) - either way, there's a bug higher up in the code. if it was correctly url-encoded it should have been ```mytext=A+%26+B+Company&anothertext=20&texttwo=SampleText&array%5B1%5D=10&array%5B2%5D=20```

Comment: @hanshenrik That's exactly what I was trying to say, although I first parsed it and then discovered the weirdness. Either way, if it is meant to be URL-encoded, the source of the string should be changed, instead of trying to make a complex parser for it that will ultimately always fail.

Comment: @hanshenrik, It helped. Now my text is encoded and able to get entire text as expected.